# How to share images on facebook using java script in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I am using facebook share button functionality but it sharing page urls but i want to share images from my code to facebook

Here is the code

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>

<script>
 (function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) 
  return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
   js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

 </script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/"
data-type="button">
</div>
```

In the above given div tag data-href i wanna pass my image urls dynamically plz help me

Answer (score 0):

you can do somthing like this

Paste this code in your  section:
Please see the image to check code http://oi62.tinypic.com/qyai4m.jpg

this will replace facebook url with your website's current url which you want to share on facebook.